# How does InputProecssor differentiate between inputs automaticlly?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

So I have a few question about some code. In here an InputProcessor is used to handle inputprocessor, but nowwhere it is defined what kind of input. Obviously it works with mouse click due to it being a code which draws buttons. But how does the Inputprocessor know what kind of input is going to come?

second question is about the button code. So the button shich is implemented there is getting a addlistener a new Changelistener, which takes an event and actor. The event would be the click via mouse right? But what is the actor= is it the button which is clicked on or is it something else?

I tried experimenting with the code and reading the documentation of libgdx and scene2d but it did not bring me a lot explanation on the questions

```
Stage HandleStage = new Stage();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(HandleStage);
--------------------------------------------------------
 Button is implemented
TextButton start= new TextButton("starts game", skin);
        start.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can no one help me?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking what is going on behind the scenes to pass input from the OS all the way down to your input processor?

Answer (score 0):

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor takes an instance of InputProcessor as Argument your `HandleStage` which is a Stage implements this interface. The InputProcessor has these methods:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode);
public boolean keyUp(int keycode);
public boolean keyTyped(char character);
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button);
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button);
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer);
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY);
public boolean scrolled(int amount);
```

Stage implements this and handles for example by a touchDown event if a Button is clicked.

I don't really understand your second question, so far I know from the `event` in changed() you can get the Target and set it to handle. Look in the Event class for more information. I think the actor is the Button but simply try it by writing: `System.out.println(actor == start);`

Comment: alright thank you, but how does that really work? for example if I click on space nothing happens obviously but when I click with my mouse it knows automatically

Comment: I don't understand your question can you make an example? How the program should know which Button you want to click by pressing space? If you will know what's going on by pressing space go in the Stage class and look for the `keyDown` method